# When does NLog capture the ThreadID?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, system.reactive, nlog

If I have async logging turned on in nlog.config, where is the `ThreadID` captured?

Context: I'm starting a greenfield project using .NET, Rx, and TPL Dataflow (a.k.a. TDP).  It will make heavy use of async operations and background work queues.

Goal: In my logging I'd like to capture the `ManagedThreadId` where the work is being performed, and when work is being done in parallel (easy to get wrong in Rx, where default scheduler isn't ThreadPool).   If I have async logging turned on in nlog.config, where is the ThreadID captured?

Concern: I don't see ThreadID in the core `LogEntry` class for NLog.  For example it isn't sent to the browser in [cbley/NLog.SignalR](https://github.com/cbley/NLog.SignalR).  If I have async logging turned on in nlog.config, where is the `ThreadID` captured?  If it isn't captured until the log entry is rendered (in an NLog background thread), then the `ThreadId` is useless to me and I need to find a more appropriate logging library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog captures the threadid corrrectly.

NLog uses `[ThreadAgnostic]` on `LayoutRender`-derived classes that can be used/rendered outside the calling thread.  Because `ThreadIdLayoutRender` doesn't have that attribute it can't be delayed until the after the async transition.

Comment: see [NLog-users google group thread](http://nlog-project.org/nlog-users?place=topic%2Fnlog-users%2FNWPFNnscd0c%2Fdiscussion).